# Как создать динамичную смену картинок при нажатии в ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

поставил себе задачу при клике на картинку like менять ее на другую в посте, чтобы пользователь понимал, что, что-либо поменялось в ***initialState*** у posts добавил значение isYouLike, которое принимает true/false идея была передавать при клике в редьюсер id поста,

```
let initialState = {
posts: [
    { id: 3, message: "Я в лазурном", date: '24 авг в 12:30', likesCount: 1, isYouLike: true},
    { id: 2, message: "It's my first post", date: '30 июл в 19:01', likesCount: 15, isYouLike: true},
    { id: 1, message: "Hello everybody", date: '30 июл в 19:00', likesCount: 3, isYouLike: false},
]}
```

замапить все посты и найти такой же id, поменять на противоположное значение isYouLike

```
const profileReduser = (state = initialState, action) => {
switch (action.type) {
case LIKE_IT:
        return{
            ...state,
            posts: state.posts.map(post => {
                debugger
                if(post.id === action.postId){
                    debugger
                    return { ...post, isYouLike: true, likesCount: post.likesCount++ }
                }
                return post
            })   
        }
    case DONT_LIKE_IT:
        return{
            ...state,
            users: state.posts.map(post => {
                if (post.id === action.userId) {
                    return { ...post, isYouLike: false, likesCount: post.likesCount--}
                }
                return post
            })
        }
    default:
        return state
}}
```

и проверку на самой картинке в компоненте

```
<div className={styles.like}>
                <div className={styles.onClickWrapper} >
                    <img src={props.isYouLike ? onClickLikePicture : likePicture} alt="Нравится" />
                </div>
                <p>{props.likesCount}</p>       
            </div>
```

На сколько я знаю onClick на саму картинку повесить нельзя, поэтому я обернул ее div'ом и при задавании ему метода onClick все ломается, картинки позываются неправильно(независимо от проверки)
вот сама проверка при клике

```
onClick={props.isYouLike ? dislike(props.id) : like(props.id)}>
```

сами функции просто передавали в редьюсер id поста, подскажите пожалуйста в чем кроется моя ошибка, сами посты я мапил .map в компоненте, которая вызывала эту компоненту

```
let postsElements =
    props.posts.map(post =>
        <Post message={post.message}
            likesCount={post.likesCount}
            postAuthor={props.postAuthor}
            isYouLike={post.isYouLike}
            date={post.date}
            id={post.id}
            key={post.id}
            likeIt={props.likeIt}
            dontLikeIt={props.dontLikeIt} />)
```

Answer (score 0):

Я бы компоненту Post сделал стейт со значением isLiked куда по дефолту положить значение из пропс isYouLike={post.isYouLike}.

```
constructor(props) {
    super();

    this.state = {
      isLiked: props.isYouLike
    };
  }
```

После этого по клику тоглить это значение в стейте и потом менять не src картинки, так как alt остается тот же. А рендерить полностью новую картинку img

```
onClick = () => this.setState(prevState => ({ isLiked: !prevState.isLiked }));

{this.state.isLiked ? <img src={likePicture} alt="Нравится" /> :  <img src={onClickLikePicture} alt="Не нравится" /> : }
```

Comment: а onClick получается на дивку повесить я должен?

Comment: Да. на блок который держит картинку.

Comment: да спасибо, получилось

Comment: А не подскажете еще по аналогии, как при клике, добавить + к лайкам количество и убрать при другом, у меня есть отдельная тоже в пропсах величина likesCount, я попробовал при likesCount: this.isLiked? this.likesCount++ : this.likesCount--, но не получилось

Comment: В таком случае лучше в компоненте родителе создать функцию которая будет сэтить posts и прокинуть эту функцию в компонент post

`setPosts = newPost => {
   const newPosts = [...this.props.posts] // копия из store
   const currentPostIndex = newPosts.findIndex(post => post.id === newPost.id);
   this.setState({posts: newPosts.splice(currentPostIndex, 1, newPost)})
}`

В эту функцию аргументом прокидывать уже новый пост лайкнутый и с новым каунтом